# Return multiple files in response in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an api with laravel and I am trying to return multiple files in a json, but I have only seen that only one is returned.

This is my method

```
        public function getImgs($id){
        $data = Data::findOrFail($id);
        $img1 = $data->img1;

        $img2 = $data->img2;
        $img3 = $data->img3;

        return response()->json([
            "img1" => file($img1),
            "img2" => file($img2),
            "img3" => file($img3),
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if data exists in all columns? TRY to print response of your query `print_r($data);die;`

Comment: Yes the data exists in fact those filds are required